# "wet" is pronounced /wetʃ/, is it a common accent?

Tags: pronunciation

I clearly heard the speaker [is pronouncing](https://youtu.be/z0Dj6j5rbKc?t=47) "wet" /wetʃ/

> you could "get wet". If you're out in the rain: "Aw, I got wet in the rain." So: "got", past tense.

Is it a common accent?

Comment: It's just a kind of "lisp". A few seconds later, she pronounces the same word as you would expect. We don't all speak perfectly all of the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've learned a new term "lisp" from you. Thank you. However I doubt that she actually pronounced "wet" /wet/. There are 4 hits in total. Each of them is pronounced /wetʃ/ in stead of /wet/

Comment: I said a *kind* of lisp, which is usally applied to the way an **S** is said. My count is 2 out of 4 but I notice the speaker has a slightly sibilant sound to many of her final **T** consonants. It's not an accent but the way *she* speaks.